# Explode MySQL string in Column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL Database and want to search a specific column for specific data.

```
{"pump":"0","track":"0","bats":"1","acc":"1","batl":"6","gpslev":"5"}
```

This is the info in the column I would like to extract bats when it is 0 and then display it on my PHP screen using PHP strings and echo.

I have read about `SUBSTRING_INDEX` but when I use it it displays everything to the left of bats. I need a search string that can search on bats and `WHERE bats=0`

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Try: `LIKE '%,"bats":"0",%'`

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? Does it support JSON functions?

Comment: @SalmanA yes it supports JSON Ver 4.0.4

Comment: You could extract the desired data using PHP functions and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JSON functions:

```
SELECT col->"$.bats"    -- and maybe other columns you want here
FROM yourTable
WHERE col->"$.bats" = '0';
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

If your version of MySQL does not support JSON functions, we can still try using `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col REGEXP '"bats":"0"';
```

Comment: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>"$.bats"   
FROM json_test
WHERE col->"$.bats" = '0'' at line 1 */

Comment: @TrevorAckermann The code is working in the demo.  Maybe your version of MySQL does not support this JSON syntax.

Comment: Let me try upgrade MySQL, I am using WAMP and accodring to WAMP I have 5.6.12 MySQL installed

Comment: I gave you a possible workaround which doesn't use the JSON functions.  But, without JSON functions there would be no easy way to extract out certain fields.

Comment: WHen I use your second string I get a reply SELECT *
FROM json_test
WHERE c REGEXP '"bats":"1"'; but it gives me the whole column details not just the BATS I need

Comment: Then it sounds like you really need the JSON functions.  My answer should work fine on version 5.7 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> create table json_test(c json);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.40 sec)

mysql> insert into json_test values('{"pump":"0","track":"0","bats":"1","acc":"1","batl":"6","gpslev":"5"}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.15 sec)

mysql> select * from json_test;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| c                                                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"acc": "1", "batl": "6", "bats": "1", "pump": "0", "track": "0", "gpslev": "5"} |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select json_extract(c,'$.bats') from json_test;
+--------------------------+
| json_extract(c,'$.bats') |
+--------------------------+
| "1"                      |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select json_extract(c,'$.bats') from json_test where json_extract(c,'$.bats') = "1";
+--------------------------+
| json_extract(c,'$.bats') |
+--------------------------+
| "1"                      |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: SQL Error (1305): FUNCTION roadside.json_extract does not exist */

Answer (score 1):

If your mysql version supports json then try below query.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, '$.bats') FROM `json_test` WHERE JSON_SEARCH(json_data, 'bats', '0%')
```